# Curl of a vector cross the vector?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, divergence-operator, curl

So I've seen that the expansion for (∇×A)×A is (A⋅∇)A−1/2(∇(A⋅A)) . [Given that A is a vector]

Now I guess it's just really late in the night, but I can't make sense of the answer - if a vector dotted with itself is a scalar, it can't have a divergence. so what's the meaning of the second term in this expansion (specifically - **∇(A⋅A)** )?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1255171/curl-of-a-vector-field-cross-itself) is an example of where one can find the identity. I must be missing something, but I don't know what it is!

Comment: It's the gradient operator and not divergence... See there's no dot after the nabla.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I was missing - a dot - thanks!